# Initialize device and create volume on device for VHD

Tags: c++, windows, vhd

I want to create a VHD, then mount it and initialize the volume, format it and mount it as a drive letter using C++/windows API's.

I can already create a VHD and attach to it using CreateVirtualDisk() and AttachVirtualDisk(), but I don't know how to initialize it and create a volume on my device (like f:) that I can see in explorer programmatically.  I have to do it via Disk Management manually in Computer Management.

I've seen the example [on a previous stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764697/create-a-virtual-partition/16629538#16629538) for creation and attachment, but not for initialization.
Anyone have any ideas?